# new list from specific index of multidimension list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm basically trying to extract some data from multidimension list into a new list. While this code does what I want, but I'm wondering if there are better ways to get this result without looping through original list?

```
aa = [
    ["a", "aa", "aaa"],
    ["b", "bb", "bbb"],
    ["c", "cc", "ccc"],
]
b = []
for a in aa:
    b.append(a[1])
b
>> Result: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

Comment: Your current code should actually return `['aa', 'bb', 'cc']`. Is this intentional, or did you mean to have `a[2]` instead of `a[1]`.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I copied the wrong part of the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> aa = [["a", "aa", "aaa"],
          ["b", "bb", "bbb"],
          ["c", "cc", "ccc"]]
>>> b = zip(*aa)[2]
>>> print b
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

I'm pretty sure `zip` still iterates through the list, but this is a much more succint way of getting the desired result.

Note that in Python 3, `zip` returns an iterator, so you need to convert to a list first

```
list(zip(*aa))[2]
```

or use a list comprehension

```
[i[2] for i in aa]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with list comprehensions:

```
>>> aa = [
["a", "aa", "aaa"],
["b", "bb", "bbb"],
["c", "cc", "ccc"],
]
>>> b = [i[2] for i in aa]
>>> print b
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use list comprehension:

```
b = [aa[i][2] for i in range(len(aa))]
```

or faster and shorter as blender has suggested

```
b = [a[2] for a in aa]
```

Comment: Why not `[a[2] for a in aa]`?

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with Numpy:

```
>>> >>> a = numpy.array([
...     ["a", "aa", "aaa"],
...     ["b", "bb", "bbb"],
...     ["c", "cc", "ccc"],
... ])
>>> a[:,2]
    array(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 
      dtype='|S3')
```